# Using singly linked list when SLIST_ENTRY is not first member of item list

Tags: c++, windows, linked-list

This is code from MSDN (using singly linked list):

```
typedef struct _PROGRAM_ITEM 
 {
    SLIST_ENTRY ItemEntry;
    ULONG Signature; 

    /* MY DATA */

 } PROGRAM_ITEM, *PPROGRAM_ITEM;

int main( )
{
    ULONG Count;
    PSLIST_ENTRY pFirstEntry, pListEntry;
    PSLIST_HEADER pListHead;
    PPROGRAM_ITEM pProgramItem;
    pListHead = (PSLIST_HEADER)_aligned_malloc(sizeof(SLIST_HEADER),
    MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT);

    InitializeSListHead(pListHead);

   // Insert 10 items into the list.
   for( Count = 1; Count <= 10; Count += 1 )
   {
     pProgramItem = (PPROGRAM_ITEM)_aligned_malloc(sizeof(PROGRAM_ITEM),
        MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT);
     pProgramItem->Signature = Count;
     pFirstEntry = InterlockedPushEntrySList(pListHead, 
                   &(pProgramItem->ItemEntry)); 
   }

   // Remove 10 items from the list and display the signature.
  for( Count = 10; Count >= 1; Count -= 1 )
   {
     pListEntry = InterlockedPopEntrySList(pListHead);

     pProgramItem = (PPROGRAM_ITEM)pListEntry;
     printf("Signature is %d\n", pProgramItem->Signature);

    _aligned_free(pListEntry);
   }

  pListEntry = InterlockedFlushSList(pListHead);
  pFirstEntry = InterlockedPopEntrySList(pListHead);
  if (pFirstEntry != NULL)
  {
    printf("Error: List is not empty.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  _aligned_free(pListHead);

  return 1;
}
```

It works well under one condition: SLIST_ENTRY must be **first** member in _PROGRAM_ITEM structure. But what if my _PROGRAM_ITEM should look like:

```
typedef struct _PROGRAM_ITEM 
{
  /* MY DATA */

  SLIST_ENTRY ItemEntry;
  ULONG Signature; 

} PROGRAM_ITEM, *PPROGRAM_ITEM;
```

In this case InterlockedPushEntrySList,InterlockedPopEntrySList etc. dont't work properly.
HOW to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be that way because `InterlockedPushEntrySList` and family take a `PSLIST_ENTRY`. If `ItemEntry` is the first item in the list, you effectively have `(void*)pProgramItem == (void*)&pProgramItem->ItemEntry`. This also means that when you pop the entry off the list, you need only cast the `PSLIST_ENTRY` back to a `PPROGRAM_ITEM`.

Having it any other way is difficult, because an `SLIST_ENTRY` is required to be aligned as per `MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT`. You would need any data in your `_PROGRAM_ITEM` struct that comes before the `SLIST_ENTRY` to be a multiple of this (or to pad out to this). Not to mention you need to do some pointer arithmetic to get your `PPROGRAM_ITEM` back from the `PSLIST_ENTRY` when you pop it off the list.

Is there any specific reason why you'd want your data to come first? It's much simpler to have the `SLIST_ENTRY` as the first data member.

Comment: the reason is that i want to store in this list  WSAOVERLAPPED extended structure, where first place is already busy for overlapped structure...

Comment: Store a pointer to the `WSAOVERLAPPED` structure in your `PROGRAM_ITEM` and dereference. No need to try to make both work in the same piece of memory.

Comment: thanks for answer, can you look to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937334/casting-issue-with-linked-list-item which refers to the above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CONTAINING_RECORD` macro to get a pointer to your data.

```
pProgramItem = (PPROGRAM_ITEM)CONTAINING_RECORD(pListEntry, PROGRAM_ITEM, ItemEntry);
```

Although the `InterlockedPushEntrySList` has an alignment requirement for its parameters. You could use a `static_assert` to ensure `ItemEntry` is aligned properly:

```
static_assert((FIELD_OFFSET(PROGRAM_ITEM, ItemEntry) % \
    MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT) == 0, "Alignment check.");
```